# ¿Por qué no devuelve el código de estado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
def main():
    #exec(open("selectorproxy.py").read())
    try:
    
        proxy1 = proxy.readline().rstrip()
        print(proxy1)
        consulta = requests.get('http://'+proxy1+'/www.web.es/es/')
        if(consulta.status_code == 200):
            print ("Success")
        else:
            print ("Fail")

    except:
        main()

    finally:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

El código cambia de proxy pero, no devuelve el código de estado y se ejecuta normalmente, ¿qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Al ejecutarlo:

> 113.177.48.183:19132

> 102.64.66.106:8080

> 178.217.140.70:443

> 178.93.151.100:8080

> 179.1.73.100:999

> 75.101.218.120:80

Como pueden ver, hace el salto de línea y recoge el proxy.

Comment: ¿Solo imprime la IP? ¿No imprime "success" ni "fail"?

Comment: Imprime fail una vez lee todas las Ips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primer paso para la resolución de problemas es usar `print()` por todas partes para ver qué está pasando:

```
import requests

def main():
    # exec(open("selectorproxy.py").read())
    try:

        proxy1 = "113.177.48.183:19132"
        print(proxy1)
        consulta = requests.get('http://' + proxy1 + '/www.web.es/es/')
        if (consulta.status_code == 200):
            print("Success")
        else:
            print("Fail")

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        main()

    finally:
        print("Finally")
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

lo que me genera este resultado:

```
113.177.48.183:19132
HTTPConnectionPool(host='113.177.48.183', port=19132): Max retries exceeded with url: /www.web.es/es/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff9934b4940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
113.177.48.183:19132
```

Lo cual explica la fuente de tus problemas: las IPs que ocupas no son válidas; no son proxies ni nada. No hay nadie escuchando en esas puertas, cosa que puedes comprobar `netcat -zv ip puerta` o simplemente un `telnet`.

Como no hay servicio escuchando, `requests.get()` falla por *timeout*, generando una excepción `NewConnectionError`. El código atrapa la excepción y genera una llamada recursiva a la misma función `main()`, lo que te hace leer el próximo proxy e intentar otra conexión (que vuelve a fallar).

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo haber arreglado el código, aunque a veces devuelve el error como indicas, otras devuelve Fail y otras "
18.198.234.64:80
('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
", ¿esto por qué puede ser? ¿debería cambiar de lista de proxys? y si da Fail ¿El proxy funciona?

Comment: No puedo especular sobre código que no veo.

Comment: try:
 
  proxy1 = proxy.readline().rstrip()
  print(proxy1)
  consulta = requests.get('http://'+proxy1+'/www.web.es/es/')
  if(consulta.status_code == 200):
   print ("Success")
  else:
   print("fail")
   main()

 except Exception as ex:
  print(ex)
  main()

 finally:
  pass

Comment: Sigues haciendo llamadas recursivas ... Es tu quinta iteración en el mismo error en menos de 24 horas.